# Truth table for incrementing and decrementing 4-bit numbers

Tags: digital-logic

A3, A2, A1 and A0 are the bits of the number which needs to be incremented/decremented. The first column with F bits is the incremented A number and the second column with F bits is the decremented A number. But I don't understand that second F column, how are those numbers decremented? It looks like they are incremented. And P columns are for bit transfers (if they cannot be put in those 4 bits).

[image]

Comment: The second F column are decremented until row six; it is a mistake in the table. And another one in the last row of the second F column, they forgot to represent a bit.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I notice that :). One more question, if we decrement 0000, if it's signed, we get 1111, but why do we have a P = 1 there?

Comment: Because there is still a carry bit there, the bits are [C][3][2][1][0] where C is the carry and the rest are your four bits. A -1 is represented in signed binary as all 1's, including the carry bit, 11111. You can see P is high anytime the four bits rollover, so P is like the carry bit, a pseudo fifth bit. Just move the P column in front of its F column and it'll be obvious.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense :D Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second F column are decremented until row six; it is a mistake in the table. And another one in the last row of the second F column, they forgot to represent a bit

> [I]f we decrement 0000, if it's signed, we get 1111, but why do we
>   have a P = 1 there?

Because there is still a carry bit there, the bits are [C][3][2][1][0] where C is the carry and the rest are your four bits. A -1 is represented in signed binary as all 1's, including the carry bit, 11111. You can see P is high anytime the four bits rollover, so P is like the carry bit, a pseudo fifth bit. Just move the P column in front of its F column and it'll be obvious.